# Transaction Management in Spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am developing a batch  using spring batch, i have two steps, a step1 that updated table1 and another step2 updated table2.

I want if the second step2 fails then all the treatment is canceled (rollback). What should I do??

I have the sample xml config  below:

```
<b:step id="Step1" parent="Tache">
    <b:tasklet>
        <b:chunk reader="baseReader" processor="baseProcessor"
             chunk-completion-policy="completionPolicy"  />
    </b:tasklet>
</b:step>

<b:step id="Step2" parent="Tache">
    <b:tasklet>
        <b:chunk reader="baseReaderEcriture" 
            writer="ecritureWriter" chunk-completion-policy="completionPolicy"  />
    </b:tasklet>
</b:step>

<b:job id="batch" parent="Batch">
    <b:step id="step1" parent="Step1" next="step2"/>
    <b:step id="step2" parent="Step2" />
</b:job>
```

Thanks!

Comment: See this. This might give an idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369876/spring-batch-and-xa-and-local-transactions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't rollback already committed data (after every chunk - based on you completition policy - your data as long as spring-batch metadata are commited), so you can't automatically rollback all data stored in step1.
Maybe you can use this syntax:

```
<b:job id="batch" parent="Batch">
    <b:step id="step1" parent="Step1" next="step2"/>
    <b:step id="step2" parent="Step2">
      <next on="ROLLBACK_ALL" to="deleteDataSavedByStep1Step" />
      <end on="*" />
    </b:step>
</b:job>
```

to move next to a step used to delete data saved by step 1, but you have to know which data you have to delete in `deleteDataSavedByStep1Step` step.

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031186/spring-batch-one-transaction-over-whole-job

Answer (score 0):

See this. This might give an idea. [Spring batch and XA and local transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369876/spring-batch-and-xa-and-local-transactions)

https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/03/transactions-in-spring-batch-part-1-the-basics/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I use a single database (datasource), I do not think I need XA transaction ? on the second link, i have already seen, but he does not speak of my case : rollback step 1 if step 2 fails...

Comment: I try the method how can i covering step1 and step2 in the same  transaction manager !! ?

Comment: read my comment on my answer; whole tx management is really a bad idea!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I hope that it can help someone else. Just need to create a step for each inspection task if these steps succeed, then launch the final step which'll save your data to database.