# Abstract Routing Data source in Spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am trying to implement AbstractRoutingDatasource in my spring batch application.
My data source gets switched at the DAO layer before calling on the method.

But the problem seems that all batch jobs in spring-batch are transaction based. 
Since they are transactional based, all the dataSource gets set before the transaction gets started and it is not possible to switch the datasources in the middle of transaction..

Are my assumptions right?? and any solution/work-around to fix it??

Comment: This wouldn't work in any Spring based application. You need to set the routing parameter before the transaction is started. So yes, your assumptions are correct.

Comment: **This wouldn't work in any Spring based application.**  Did you mean Spring batch?? But what about the batch jobs?? Abstract routing data source can never be applied to spring-batch??

Comment: maybe this can work, but you have to span tx using XA; I haven't used them look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369876/spring-batch-and-xa-and-local-transactions

Comment: I meant really any general Spring based application (not just *spring-batch* based). *JDBC connection* is requested from the *data source* when a *transaction manager* starts transaction. So the routing can happen only when TX is started.

Comment: Btw. check this great article about transaction handling in spring-batch (if you haven't read them already) - https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/03/transactions-in-spring-batch-part-1-the-basics/ (don't forget to read part 2 and 3 as well). There are several places where you can do "TX magic" in sprgin-batch.

Comment: Btw. if you want to help with your specific use-case, please share some more information on why you need routing data source in a batch process. In general it does not make sense to have routing data source in a batch. But your use-case might be special. Thank you.

Comment: I would like to switch data source based on the query I execute (read only queries in one database and DML in another source). In my spring batch jobs, i have process which try to read from the database as well as update if required. Hence i would like to switch the datasource inside the job. But spring batch jobs being transactional, would not allow me to switch in between..:(

Comment: DataSource routing should be done on some thread local variable. This variable must be set before the transaction begins. You can use `StepExecutionListener` to set up routing variable for the whole step or `ChunkListener` to set up routing variable for each chunk (portion of read data). The latter would be a bit more complex as you will need to play with the chunk completion policies or the step implementation itself. 
I would suggest to rethink your approach and maybe implement two jobs: one *generic job* for your batch and one *starter job* which will run *generic job* for each data source.

Answer (score -1):

Using routing data source requires a map which provides key of your choice and value which is data source. You decide what type of key to use - for example Locale for different countries. Then in a class which implements AbstractRoutingDataSource you provide a key which is retrieved from data source map.

So yes - map is configured during application set up, but your AbstractRoutingDataSource dynamically decide which data source to use.

```
@Override
protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
    return LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
}
```

Comment: I clearly understand how to switch the data sources based on the key. May be my question is not clear.

It so happens that data sources cannot be switched inside a transactional methods..(@Transactional).  And it seems that processor steps (Reader, processor, writer in spring batch) follows transactional behaviour and hence data source switch not happening inside once the process starts...And I would like to know if any has solved this?

Comment: Guys, any solution to this problem ? I also in trouble, please advice.